# How to translate a data structure in Python into an XML structure

Tags: python, xml, serialization

I have an XML example with data. I need to create the structure of this document using python, fill it with random data and upload it back to XML in order to get the same valid XML

I created a structure where each complex element from XML is an instance of the corresponding class, built a hierarchy (the lower-level complex element is an attribute of the higher-level class). Simple elements are simply attribute variables of base types.

Now a question. How can I wrap my class instance (the topmost one in the hierarchy containing all the rest) in XML so that the XML hierarchy is clearly built?

Tried through serialization in pickle, but as I understand it, serialization is a simple encoding of an object, not a conversion to a structure of a specific format. Correct me if I'm wrong. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Check https://pypi.org/project/dicttoxml/

Comment: We need more specifics here especially the overall background to avoid the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you need to *wrap your class instance in XML*? Why not continue using Python? (A cure to xy problem is to ask *why* 5 times!) XML is not really a coding environment.